# IP header bit order not clear

Tags: c++, c, ip, pcap

I read the IP RFC and in there it says the 4 first bits of the IP header is the version. In the drawing it also shows that bits 0 to 3 are the version.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1

But when I look at the first byte of the header (as captured using pcap lib) I see this byte:

0x45

This is a version 4 IP header but obviously bits 4 to 7 are equal to 4 and not bits 0 to 3 as I expected.

I expected doing a bitwise and on first byte and 0x0F will get me the version but it seems that I need to and with 0xF0.

Am I missing something? Understanding something incorrectly?

Comment: Seems like and endianness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue.

Comment: I thought about endiannes too but realized that he's getting the right result. @Mormegil answer is correct.

Comment: Note that “endianness” sensu stricto refers to the ordering of _bytes_ within larger structures, not to the numbering of _bits_ inside a byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-39) of the RFC:

> Whenever an octet represents a numeric quantity the left most bit in the
> diagram is the high order or most significant bit.  That is, the bit
> labeled 0 is the most significant bit.  For example, the following
> diagram represents the value 170 (decimal).

```
                        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
                       |1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0|
                       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Which means everything is correct except for your assumption that the “first four bits” are the *least*-significant, while those are the *most*-significant.

E.g. in the 7th and 8th bytes, containing the flags and the fragment offset, you can separate those as follows (consider that pseudocode, even though it is working C#):

```
byte flagsAndFragmentHi = packet[6];
byte fragmentLo = packet[7];
bool flagReserved0 = (flagsAndFragmentHi & 0x80) != 0;
bool flagDontFragment = (flagsAndFragmentHi & 0x40) != 0;
bool flagMoreFragments = (flagsAndFragmentHi & 0x20) != 0;
int fragmentOffset = ((flagsAndFragmentHi & 0x1F) << 8) | (fragmentLo);
```

Note that the more significant (left-shifted 8 bits) portion of the fragment offset is in the first byte (because IP works in big endian). Generally: bits on the left in the diagram are always more significant.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is only for numeric fields? The flags field is the low bits, even though it appears on the left bits of the byte? But the seventh byte consists of both flags and part of a numeric field, the fragment offset. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: I have appended an example. And no, the flags are the high (more significant) bits, _because_ they appear in the left (lower-numbered) bits in the diagram.

Comment: Thank you. That clarified things up for me :-)